# Can the Anymote protocol get the current channel from the Google TV device?

Tags: android, google-tv

Given that Google TV is going to be integrated into some sets, I'm assuming that the current channel is stored somewhere that the GTV OS can retrieve it. If that is the case, I'm wondering if there's a request that the Anymote protocol can make upon authentication so that it can get the current channel that the TV is tuned to from the TV set.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reliable way to get the current channel.  It would have privacy implications if you could.

Comment: Perhaps it should be made a permission the app must request? Seems like fairly basic functionality.